# Python webdriverwait or expected_conditions doesnt work for me

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Hi everyone I am learning python and trying create macro in web-browser game but I couldnt access login part yet.I am just stuck it on button click

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\batuh\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.adaletank.com/")
myPageTittle = driver.title
print(myPageTittle)

assert "AdaletTank | Bombom Pvp Server" in myPageTittle
print("Page loaded succesfuly")

loginbuton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/span[1]")
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=3).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable(loginbuton))
loginbuton.click()
```

Without webdriverwait it just doesnt work so I have to load the button first but some reason I cannot find the button

I got this error

```
return driver.find_element(*by)
TypeError: selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be        an iterable, not FirefoxWebElement
```

Answer (score 0):

The `expected_conditions` functions takes an iterable as its argument, as seen in the error. I believe you can use this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

xpath = "/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/span[1]"
loginbuton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
WebDriverWait(
    driver, timeout=3
).until(
    ec.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, xpath)
    )
).click()
```

Importing `By` is an additional `import` statement which you will need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just didnt know we have to import by part.
unfortunately my biggest issue was not loading button it says now 
is not clickable at point (557,503) because another element <div> obscures it
probably too many div is covering it any suggestions ?

Comment: Depending on your website, it will be a variety of things. In my experiences, the elements have most often been ads on-screen. Usually there is an element which corresponds to the **X** which closes the ad. If you do a `browser.find_element_*().click()` call, you should be able to close the ad.